# Prove that the unique solution of this heat equation is of the form...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How can I prove the following?

Prove that the unique solution of

$$\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx}=0,&x\in \mathbb{R},t>0\\
u(x,0)=x^2,&x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$$

With $u_{xxx}\in L^\infty (\mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty))$ is of the form

$$u(x,t)=A(t)x^2+B(t)x+C(t)$$

I know how to prove the existence of a function of that form that is solution of the problem, but how can I prove it's unique? If the initial data was $C(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, then the solution would be unique in $C^2(\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty))\cap C(\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty))\cap L^\infty (\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty))$, but $x^2$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. How can I use the fact that $u_{xxx}\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty))$.

Answer (score 0):

if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are two solutions, then $u = u_1 - u_2$ are is a solution of the homogenous problem
$$\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx}=0&x\in \mathbb{R},t>0\\
u(x,0)=0&x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{cases}$$
So prove that $u = 0$ is the only solution to the homogenous equation.